# Javascript convert alert to string

Tags: javascript, string, alert

I have this small javascript to validate form input.

```
function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) {
var reason = "";

  reason += validateEmail(theForm.courriel);

  if (reason != "") {
    alert("Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function trim(s)
{
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}
```

I'm tryin to figure out how to get the "alert" message as a string to show it later on the page instead of popping this ridiculous box. Looks simple to me but i'm a big zero in js. Any help appreciated, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The alert() method is what makes the big pop up box.  If you want to save the value for later use save it to a variable.  Something like:

```
var message = "";
function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) {
   var reason = "";

   reason += validateEmail(theForm.courriel);

   if (reason != "") {
      message = "Some fields need correction:\n" + reason;
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}

function trim(s)
{
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}
```

Comment: The script works normaly but the message does not show

Comment: The message does not show because nothing is being done with it.  You would need to add some code to display the message in whatever way you want to show it.  One way is to create a specific div in the HTML and assign the value of message to its textContent:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/yfc4b32c%28v=vs.94%29.aspx.  (Also, I edited by answer to make message global, as @Lekhnath suggested on a different answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var alerter;

function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) {
var reason = "";

  reason += validateEmail(theForm.courriel);

  if (reason != "") {
    alerter = "Some fields need correction:<br/>" + reason;
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function trim(s)
{
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}

document.body.innerHTML = alerter;
```

Comment: `alerter` will remain `undefined`. It should be a global variable or you should remove `var` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning the string to a property of "window" :

```
window.myAlert ="Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
```

Then you can get it from anywhere:

```
document.body.innerHTML = window.myAlert;
```

Comment: I get a blank page saying "undefined"

Comment: If your "reason" var was empty, it wouldn't get defined, so you'd have to account for that.

Comment: * by "it" I mean window.myAlert